# Continuation of loop on error

Tags: r

I have a function within a loop and I would like the loop to continue if there is an error.
I have tried:

```
for (num in 1:20) {
    tryCatch(fnABC(num),error=0)
}
```

But the loop stops on an error and I get a message:

> Error in tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]]) :
>   attempt to apply non-function

I would be greatful to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can I ask what your rationale was for setting `error = 0` given what the documentation for `tryCatch` says, as well as the examples?

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. From documentation I tried  tryCatch.W.E( fnABC(num)) and this seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "try" function to accomplish your task:

```
for (num in 1:20) {
    try({
        fnABC(num)
    }, silent=T)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error argument to tryCatch is supposed to be a function, although unlike @joran I was unable to see this documented in any of the Details section of the help page. It is apparent, however,  from the 4th example (and if you were in the proper frame of mind from the error message.)

Comment: I was referring to this: "If a handler is found then...the handler is called with the condition as its argument, and the result returned by the handler is returned as the value of the tryCatch call." but perhaps that is a bit opaque.

Comment: It was for me. I suspect my level of abstraction is intermediate between yours and @adam.888's.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (num in 1:20) {
tryCatch(fnABC(num),error = function(e) {error=0 } )
}
```